# Translate pricing to a pattern in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to update all pricing to end in .15 no matter what it currently reads.  By that, I mean to round the existing price to the nearest dollar and then add 0.15.  So, for example, $2.49 would become $2.15, and $2.50 would become $3.15.

I need the amount to end with exactly .15.  As of right now I have formatted the cells to only show two digits past the decimal, but when I click on the number, it shows to really be ten digits passed the decimal.

I have a number of pricing tiers I need to update to end in a certain penny amount and am hoping there is a way to do it more efficiently than 'one by one'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `=ROUND(A1,0)+0.15` For this you will need a cell with actual value somewhere that you edit; the formula will give you the resulting value.

Answer (score 0):

`=ROUND(A1,2)` will round your value to two decimal points. If you just want the resulting value, you can then copy/paste-value the result back into the original cell.